# wordpress PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ..wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 3961

Tags: php, wordpress

In mode debug my `error_log` show this error:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in ../public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 3961

This is my taxonomy.php file: (same as original WordPress)

```
if ( $t->rewrite['hierarchical'] ) {
    $hierarchical_slugs = array();
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, $taxonomy, 'taxonomy' );
    foreach ( (array)$ancestors as $ancestor ) {
        $ancestor_term = get_term($ancestor, $taxonomy);
        $hierarchical_slugs[] = $ancestor_term->slug;
    }
    $hierarchical_slugs = array_reverse($hierarchical_slugs);
    $hierarchical_slugs[] = $slug;
    $termlink = str_replace("%$taxonomy%", implode('/', $hierarchical_slugs), $termlink);
} else {

...
```

Line 3961 is:

```
$hierarchical_slugs[] = $ancestor_term->slug;
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that `get_term($ancestor, $taxonomy);` is not returning a term.  `get_term` can return null or WP_Error.

Can you do `var_dump($ancestor_term);` before line 3961

Ideally you would wrap that line in an if condition:

```
if(isset($ancestor_term->slug)){
    $hierarchical_slugs[] = $ancestor_term->slug;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omar for your early response.

Comment: The problem is that (as I can see from your var_dump) in the third loop is `get_term` is returning **NULL** returning and therefore cannot fetch ->slug from NULL.

If this fixed your issue please set as Best Answer :)

Comment: Of course, but ... How can I set your response like "Best Answer"? .xD Sorry, I´m a new person here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Regarding issue when updating wordpress,i think you need to refresh the permalinks: https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/